# Did I do PDO right? First timer at prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, insert

Just changed my previous question to reflect PDO changes everyone told me to make. Am I doing this right? Error reporting right? Is everything secure?

Just changed my previous question to reflect PDO changes everyone told me to make. Am I doing this right? Error reporting right? Is everything secure?

```
try{
$connection = new PDO('mysql:host=supertopsecret;dbname=supertopsecret;charset=utf8mb4', 
'supertopsecret', 'supertopsecret');
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

//Query 1 - Insert Provider's Name
//if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ delete this? do I still use this? halp
$stmt1 = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO 
`providers`(provider_first_name,provider_last_name,date_added)
VALUES (:providerfirstname, :providerlastname, NOW())");

//bind parameters:
  $stmt1->bindParam(':providerfirstname', $providerfirstname);
  $stmt1->bindParam(':providerlastname', $providerlastname);

//insert row
  $providerfirstname = $_POST['providerfirstname'];
  $providerlastname = $_POST['providerlastname'];

  $stmt1->execute();

//Query 2 - Insert Practices
$prov_id = $connection->lastInsertId();
  /*Get all values of practice_name[]:*/
  $practicename = $_POST['practice_name'];
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($practicename); $i++) {
      if ($practicename[$i]) {
          $practice_name_data = $practicename[$i];


      $stmt2 = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO 
practices(prov_id,practice_name) VALUES (:prov_id,:practice_name)");

      $stmt2->bindParam(':prov_id', $prov_id);
      $stmt2->bindParam(':practice_name', $practice_name_data);

      $stmt2->execute();
     }
  }


echo '<center><h3><br><br><br>Thank you! Your provider has 
successfully been submitted to the database!</center></h3></br>';

} catch(PDOException $e){
echo "Sorry, there was an problem submitting your provider to the 
database. Please try again or copy and paste the error code below to 
the \"Report a Problem\" page and we will try to correct the problem. 
</b></br></br> Error: " . $e->getMessage();
die();
}
$connection = null;
```

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: 1You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 11You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

Comment: `echo $practicename[0];` and check if it has data or not.

Comment: Is it because I didn't escape the providername?

Comment: Codebreaker, the data is there exactly as I entered it

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, just updated my code above with PDO, feedback welcomed!! first time trying it

Answer (score 0):

You should use prepared statements instead of escaping yourself, see [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?r=SearchResults&s=1|1036.6918).  But it's probably `'$practicename[$i]'`.  It would be `'{$practicename[$i]}'`, but easier:

```
foreach($practicename as $value){
   if($value!=""){
       $value =  mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $value);
       $query2 = mysqli_query($connection,
       "INSERT INTO `practices`(prov_id,practice_name) 
        VALUES ('$prov_id','$value')");
   }
}
```

But again, abandon this and use [Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)!

Comment: Okay, I will switch from mysqli escapes to PDO and see if that fixes it, it's about time I started doing that anyway I guess, thank you

Comment: PDO is preferred and I would switch but see my second link for mysqli.

Comment: how do my prepared statements look? i updated code above

Answer (score 0):

Check this it may help you. Use PDO for insert.

```
$connection = new PDO("mysql:host=xxxx;dbname=xxxx;", "xxxx", "xxxx"); //database connection

for ($i = 0; $i < count($practicename); $i++) {
    if ($practicename[$i]) {
        $practice_name_data = $practicename[$i];

        $statement = $connection->prepare('INSERT INTO practices(prov_id,practice_name) VALUES (:prov_id,:practice_name)');

        $statement->bindParam(':prov_id', $prov_id);
        $statement->bindParam(':practice_name', $practice_name_data);
        // etc.

        $statement->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: hugely helpful, I've never used PDO so I'm a little lost, thank you!!

Comment: Welcome to the PDO.Cheers! :) :) @mb9393

Comment: if I use this, i ditch using mysqli_real_escape_string entirely?

Comment: You could use `foreach` here instead of `for` loop.

Comment: how do my prepared statements look? i updated code above